# bulk search and copy files on a mac

Tags: mac, finder, automator, search, data

So i had previously used a software where i could paste a list of file names and automate it to copy all those files and paste into destination folder. Unfortunately i am unable to find it.

So the problem i have now is "how can i bulk search and copy files from a folder to destination folder"

So,
I have a folder with around 2000 images.
and i have all these images names in an excel.

So i have already selected few image names on that excel which i can curate in a plaintext too.
But i am unable to find a way search these names and copy those files into another folder.

I really hope there is someone here who can help me find a solution.

Looking forward to all the help and suggestions

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the images names do not contain any newline characters, you can do the following:

- Create a new Excel file with just the column containing the image names
- Save this file as CSV into the folder with the images as `imagelist.csv`
- Open Terminal
- Type `cd`  (including the trailing space) and drag&drop the image folder from Finder into Terminal, then press Enter
- Type `perl -pi -e 's/\r\n/\n/;' imagelist.csv` and press Enter to remove DOS-style line endings
- Type (or copy&paste) `sed 1d imagelist.csv | while read -r image; do cp -v "$image"`  into Terminal (again including the trailing space), **do not** press Enter yet
- Drag&drop the destination folder from Finder into Terminal
- Type (or copy&paste) `; done`, then press Enter

This should copy all the images named in the CSV, and print their name while doing so.